# How to display XML sub menu of sub menu and display image if it is last node

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, xml

I am working on one task for school, I want to display a menu from an XML file.

Here is the XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<menus>
    <menu text="Subjects">
        <menu text="English">
            <school text="English A" image="E_A.png" />
            <school text="English B" image="E_B.png" />
        </menu>
        <menu text="Maths">
            <school text="Maths A" image="M_A.jpg" />
            <school text="Maths B" image="M_B.jpg" />
        </menu>
    </menu>
    <menu text="Teachers">
        <school text="Sara" image="phones/sara.jpg" />
        <school text="Maya" image="phones/maya.jpg" />
    </menu>
</menus>
```

My HTML markup looks like that:

```
<section class="intro">
    <div class="inner">
        <div class="content">
            <h1>Welcome</h1>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
<footer id="footer">
    <nav id="nav">

    </nav>
</footer>
```

I am using jQuery and JavaScript to read data from XML file and display in the navigation bar. The JavaScript and jQuery code for that is given.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "record.xml",
        dataType: "xml",
        success: function(xml) {
            html = generateMenu(xml);
        }
    });
});

function generateMenu(xml) {
    var mainMenu = $("<ul />");
    $(xml).find('menu').each(function() {
        if ($(this).children().length) {
            var subMenu = $("<ul />");
            $(this).children().each(function() {
                subMenu.append('<li id="' + $(this).attr("text") + '"><a href="#">' + $(this).attr("text") + '</a></li>');
            });
            var li = $('<li id="' + $(this).attr("text") + '"><a href="#">' + $(this).attr("text") + '</a></li>');
            mainMenu.append(li.append(subMenu));
        } else {
            mainMenu.append('<li id="' + $(this).attr("text") + '"><a href="#">' + $(this).attr("text") + '</a></li>');
        }
    });
    $("#nav").append(mainMenu);
}
```

The CSS you will help you to understand the logic going on.

```
html, body {
    background-color: #f0efed;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;
}
.intro {
    height: 90%;
    width: 100%;
    margin: auto;
    top: 0;
    display: table;
}
.intro .inner {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
    width: 100%;
    max-width: none;
}
.content {
    max-width: 90%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 20px 20px 40px 20px;
}
.content h1 {
    font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
    text-shadow: 0px 0px 300px #000;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    font-size: 225%;
}
#footer {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 10%;
    font-family: Arial;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px black;
    border-top: 1px solid #dbdbdb;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    box-shadow: inset 0 1px rgba(255,255,255,0.3), inset 0 10px rgba(255,255,255,0.2), inset 0 10px 20px rgba(255,255,255,0.25),inset 0 -15px 30px rgba(255,255,255,0.3);
}

nav {
    width: 100%;
    background: #ffffff;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    height: 60px;
    position:relative;
}
nav ul {
    background: #ffffff;
    list-style:none;
    padding:0 20px;
    margin: 0;
    height: 60px;

}
nav ul li {
    display: inline-block;
}
nav ul li a {
    color:#333333;
    display:block;
    padding:0px 40px;
    text-decoration:none;
    float: left;
    height: 50px;
    line-height: 50px;
}
nav ul li:hover {
    background: #205791;
    border-radius: 20px;
}
nav ul li:hover > a{
    color:#ffffff;
}

nav ul li:hover > ul {
  display:block;
}
nav ul ul {
    background: #ffffff;
    padding:0;
    display:none;
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: -61px;
    left: 0px;
}
```

Display: Then menu looks like that
[image]

[In case if you want to see the code in action here is the link to jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ziakhan/c5ghc80s/2/)

Issue: As you can see the English and Math are showing in the parent node, and at the same time it is showing in the child node. When I mouse over on Egnlish which is in parent node it shows English A, English B. I want it in the proper order.

I also want to fire an event to display image in content div base on mouse over on the last node.

The structure flow will be something like that.
[image]
I will appreciate your help. Thank you!

Comment: Hey user3144924, attaching CSS might help, as the looks are achieved by styling. Can you put that into jsfiddle or anything like that?    
    
Having working example will greatly increase the chance of receiving a proper answer.

Comment: Thank you for your response and advice. I will update the question

Comment: Can you please check it again. I added the style and jsfiddle link

Comment: When using your jsfiddle link, I can only see the content of your XML, nothing else. Working example is what we need here.

Comment: This was a mistake in the link. I am sorry for that. I fixed it now. I just lost in links.

Comment: Ok, we're getting close :) 

i've updated your fiddle to actually work and display the menu -> http://jsfiddle.net/c5ghc80s/6/ Now if you would be able to explain what do you mean by "I want it in the proper order."

Comment: If you see the xml, I want to display Subjects and Teacher. Then in Subjects English and Math and in English -> English A and English B.

Comment: I added an image to understand the flow. I hope it will help us to clarify what exactly I want.

Comment: It takes a lot of effort to explain the task, doesn't it? :) I've added an answer to your question. Have a look!

Comment: I checked the answer, we are very close. The menu is almost done. The only issue is the last node. When you click on Teachers is show only Sara, but bot sibling Maya. It shows the Maya like child node of Sara. In the XML they are on the same Node.   In Subject, it works great but in last node it do not show Maths B or English B

Comment: Yes, to fix that I had to change XML school nodes. Check the URL to fiddle I posted below the code. It is updated there.

Comment: It is working fine. I am very confused. When I add the function to my normal code, I mean a call from Ajax it did not show anything. Can you please add the code, like my JavaScript section, and keep the xml file separate no with HTML. here is link to actual xml file which I want to use in my project .. http://join.manhattanmode.se/projects/products.xml

Comment: Hi Adrian, It works I add $(xml).find('menus').children('menu').each(function() ... and it works. I can access all the nodes. The only thing which is ramming is to display the image in the div tag. How it will be possible. Thank you for your support

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have used find, which has ignored the structure of child nodes. 
Also your script is missing iteration through Sub-menu level 2

Here is corrected JS code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {    
    generateMenu();      
});

function generateMenu(xml) {
    var emptySubMenu = $("<ul />");
    var mainMenu = $("<ul />");

    $('menus').children('menu').each(function() {       
            var li = generateLiNode($(this).attr("text"));

            //get subMenu level 1             
            var subMenuLvl1 = $("<ul />");
            $(this).children().each(function() {
                  var li2 = generateLiNode($(this).attr("text"));

                  //get subMenu level 2  
                  var subMenuLvl2 = $("<ul />");
                  $(this).children().each(function() {
                      subMenuLvl2.append(generateLiNode($(this).attr("text")));                
                  });

                  if (subMenuLvl2.html() != emptySubMenu.html())
                    li2.append(subMenuLvl2);                 
                  //subMenu level 2 is prepared.

                  subMenuLvl1.append(li2);
            });

            if (subMenuLvl1.html() != emptySubMenu.html())
                li.append(subMenuLvl1);
            //subMenu level 1 is prepared.

            mainMenu.append(li);        
    });

    $("#nav").append(mainMenu);
}

function generateLiNode(text)
{
    return $('<li id="' + text + '"><a href="#">' + text + '</a></li>')
}
```

and also a working JSFiddle: 
http://jsfiddle.net/c5ghc80s/8/

Your second question can be solved by 3 steps:

1. Pass 2nd parameter to generateLiNode, the same way you are passing "text" right now but this time with "image"
2. Print the image attribute next to "id" attribute
3. In document ready function, after generateMenu(), register onhover event 
   where you will do whatever you want with the image attribute of current li node.

For example you can take it out from li element and put into src attribue of img node which can be placed in your main div:

```
$("li").mouseover(function() {
  $('div > img').attribute("source", $("this").attribute("image"));
});
```

Comment: Cool, it works. I want to display the image in the content if someone mouse over on the last node. How it can be possible.

Comment: Hey, have a look at additional info above. Cheers!

Comment: Hi, I want to replace the mouse over with a click. Can you please help me with that.

Comment: It's as easy as replacing a word "mouseover" with "click". Check the example here: https://jsfiddle.net/o95dq69m/

Comment: I tried it and it is working. I added one function if you want to have a look.

Comment: Hi are you live? can you please check my one question?